# How to filter a row based on a string, but only if the string occurs multiple times

Tags: r, stringr

I'm working on cleaning up a data set. An example of the set is below. As you can see, the first entry has multiple occurrences of `vs.` I want to filter out any rows that have multiple occurrences, as I just want matches between two wrestlers.

```
2008-03-29 KO-D Openweight Title Number 1 Contendership Four Way Dance: Great Yago (Yoshiaki Yago) vs. I Am Chono Sanshiro (Sanshiro Takagi) vs. Koo vs. Seiya Morohashi - No Contest
1935-04-17  Lou Thesz Vs. Otto Kuss Ime Limit Draw 
1976-05-09  Harley Race Vs. The Destroyer Ime Limit Draw
```

I'm trying the following, but its not working. I'm not sure what else I should try.

```
dataset_final <- dataset %>%
filter(
!str_detect(match, "( vs. | Vs. ){2,}")
)
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this filter would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stringr` package has a function called `str_count` that can be used

```
dataset <- structure(list(date = c("2008-03-29", "1935-04-17", "1976-05-09"
), str = c("KO-D Openweight Title Number 1 Contendership Four Way Dance: Great Yago (Yoshiaki Yago) vs. I Am Chono Sanshiro (Sanshiro Takagi) vs. Koo vs. Seiya Morohashi - No Contest",
"Lou Thesz Vs. Otto Kuss Ime Limit Draw", "Harley Race Vs. The Destroyer Ime Limit Draw"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))


library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)

dataset %>% 
mutate(str_low = tolower(str)) %>% filter(str_count(str_low, 'vs.') < 2) %>% 
select(date, str)
```

Comment: Hey, I appreciate this answer. ```str_count``` was the way to go. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

This splits the strings on vs. and then counts the length.  This returns the first row with a date of 2008-03-29

```
df1$count <- lengths(strsplit(df1$V2, 'vs.'))
df1[df1$count > 1, ]
```

Filter in single pass

```
df1[lengths(strsplit(df1$V2, 'vs.')) > 1, ]
```

Test data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("2008-03-29", "1935-04-17", "1976-05-09"
), V2 = c("KO-D Openweight Title Number 1 Contendership Four Way Dance: Great Yago 
(Yoshiaki Yago) vs. I Am Chono Sanshiro (Sanshiro Takagi) vs. Koo vs. Seiya Morohashi 
- No Contest", 
"Lou Thesz Vs. Otto Kuss Ime Limit Draw ", "Harley Race Vs. The Destroyer Ime Limit Draw "
), count = c(4L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```